# Query doesn't update correctly in mySql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having problems with a query that should "rank an user to 3" but instead in the MySQL it gives to the user X rank 0.

Here is the code

```
    if($_POST['rank'] == '3')
  {
   mysql_query("UPDATE users SET rank='3' AND LPT='1' where username='".$_post['u_name']."' LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
   $query = true;
  }
```

Waiting for answers

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated. For the query try this without the AND between updated columns: mysql_query("UPDATE users SET rank='3', LPT='1' where username='".$_POST['u_name']."' LIMIT 1"). Also use PDO with prepared statements to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: its $_POST not $_post, and using it raw is asking for trouble

Comment: that isn't how UPDATE works. RT*M http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: This is a fine case of "debug my code". Well here. Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code. You'll be sure to avoid another question next time.

Comment: *"Here is the code"*... you should also have told us: *"Here is the error"* from your use of `or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: @Dagon Not just "trouble", but ["Double Trouble..."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Trouble_(band))

Answer (score 4):

Use comma instead of `AND` when updating multiple columns:

```
UPDATE users 
SET rank='3', 
    LPT='1' 
where username= ?
```

You should:

1. Use parametrized query instead of concatenating SQL string
2. `$_post` is a superglobal and must be in uppercase `$_POST`

   - Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Additional reference:

- UPDATE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: you should add the fact about `$_post` that's a superglobal http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php and SQL injection as a bonus ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- lad2025 [cunningly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AsXKS8Nyu8Q) leaves the post out of it :-)

Comment: @Dagon Or a [common cunning linguist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_A6D2JN8ReM)